# ASP.Net mvc 4 DropDownListFor not selecting the Selected Value

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository = new UserRepository();

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> users
    {
        get
        {
            var result =  _userRepository.GetAllUsers()
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                   Value = x.UserID,
                   Text = x.Name
                });
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

TestView.cshtml

```
@model TestNamespace.TestViewModel

<h2>Test</h2>
@Html.DropDownListFor(x =>x.UserID,
    new SelectList(Model.users,"Value","Text"), "--Select User--"       
)
```

When I select the value in the dropdownlist the value is not getting selected. I have written a jquery `.change()` which is not being raised. $("#UserID").change();

It's showing *"The field UserID must be a number"*.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#UserID").change(function () {
        alert("Test");
    });
});
```

Comment: show your javascript code please

Comment: As I can see, problem on client side, post html-markup (select, options and etc). Error message comes from server or unobstructive validation?

Comment: Thanks , my jquery-1.7.1.min.js was an issue, but it didn't show up in firebug in Firefox , but when i opened in IE & used developer tools it showed the script error .